# skip view without the user knowing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, controller, segue

I want to be able to skip to the nth view in a flow without the user knowing that there are previous views on the stack. I am able to skip with the code below but it is visible and if i try the same code in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear then the segue doesn't work.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(false)
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToAddressView", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create an additional segue with a new identifier that goes directly to the view you want. Call that instead.

Comment: i need the skipped views in the stack so that won't work